# Show that if $f$ has a local maximum at $a$, then Schwarz's second derivative at $a$ is $\leq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have the following statment:

- Show that if $f$ has a local maximum at $a$, then Schwarz's second derivative at $a$ is $\leq 0$.

Recalling the definition of Schwarz's second derivative:

> If $f''(a)$ exists, then $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)+f(a-h)-2f(a)}{h^2} $

From this statement, to justifiy that if $f$ has a local maximum at $a$, we have the following theorem:

- $f$ is a twice differentiable function, then:

1. If $f$ has a local maximum at $a$, then $f''(a)\leq 0$
2. If $f$ has a local minimum at $a$, then $f''(a)\geq 0$

Using item $1$ from this theorem, wouldn't be sufficient to prove that Schwarz's second derivative at $a$ is $\leq 0$?